# How can I modify props values once the page has been refreshed in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

My test code is the following, it's just an example to understand my question.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  account: Object,
})

const { account } = toRefs(props);

const accountDate = ref("")

const formatDate = (date) => {
    var d = new Date(date)
    var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1)
    var day = '' + d.getDate()
    var year = d.getFullYear()

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

onMounted(() => {
    accountDate.value = formatDate(account.value.date)
    console.log(account.value.date)
})

</script>

<template>
    <input type="text" v-model="accountDate"></input>
</template>
```

So the "formatDate" function just transforms Date format to YYYY-MM-DD, it's not important in my question. So I v-model accountDate with the new Date format but the console.log shown just print "undefined". So props are not defined yet in onMounted lifecycle.
How can I do it?

Comment: What is the object you're passing to the `account` prop, does it correctly includes a `date` property without being undefined?

Comment: Yes! if in <template> I put for example <p>{{ account.date }}</p> it is shown fine

Comment: Maybe your prop isn't defined yet when reaching the `mounted` hook, so it's likely a problem with your parent component if you expect it to be defined directly when you create the component?

Comment: This component have 4 parents up so account is defined in their parents... I don't know what to do

Comment: it's [bad practice to mutate props](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow).  they shouldn't be used with v-model.  set the v-model to some data value initialized using the prop and emit changes to the parent which should handle the mutation instead.  to format the value, use a [computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) property and set it as the input's `:value` prop, e.g. `<input :value="computedProperty" v-model="dataProperty">`

Comment: @yoduh he doesn't mutate the props, it copies its value into `accountDate` ref on mounted hook, but it's undefined at this point.

Comment: @Mark You'd have to debug your parent component to understand why the prop is undefined when the child component mounts. Otherwise, you can use `watch` to react to your prop change and update `accountDate` accordingly everytime the prop updates :)

Comment: @Kapcash my alternative solution is always to use watch but sometimes doesn't react to changes

Comment: So in a regular situation, I would be able to acces props values on onMounted hook? So as you said the problem is in parents components right?

Comment: Yes exactly, when mounted, you can access the props if they are defined by the parent.